# Angular2 Can I pass custom parameters to Host Listener event

Tags: angular

Here is my current Host Listener

```
 @HostListener('document:myCustomEvent', ['$event'])
 updateNodes(event) {
    console.log(this.variable);
 }
```

And I'm calling it here:

```
var event = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
event.initCustomEvent('myCustomEvent', true, true,
  true);
```

document.dispatchEvent(event);

My question is, can I pass my custom parameters to updateNodes ? For instance:

```
@HostListener('document:myCustomEvent', ['$event'])
updateNodes(event, param1, param2) {
 console.log(this.variable);
 console.log(param1);
 console.log(param2);
 }
```

Comment: Where do you pass `param1` and `param2`?

Answer (score 16):

Dispatch event this way:

```js
var event = new CustomEvent(
    'myCustomEvent',
    { detail: { 'param1': 1, 'param2': 2 } }
);

document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

and then

```
@HostListener('document:myCustomEvent', ['$event', '$event.detail.param1', '$event.detail.param2'])
updateNodes(event, param1, param2) {
    console.log(param1);
    console.log(param2);
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/2kiYCNiQiA0hlHgg2L0T?p=preview)**

Comment: is it possible to pass custom parameters in HostListener function?