# Angular 4 dispatchEvent with custom event

Tags: angular, typescript, events

My requirment is to fire event from the code to a parent hosting component.

I used the first answer here as a reference: [angular2 manually firing click event on particular element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639486/angular2-manually-firing-click-event-on-particular-element)

If I try this, it works well:

```
this.itemHost.viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

In the parent component I wrote this:

```
(click)="go()"
```

It arrives to the go method when the above code occurs.

But this doesn't work if I do it with some custom event name, e.g.:

```
this.itemHost.viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('customEvent'));
```

and in the parent component:

```
(customEvent)="go()"
```

How can I do it with custom event?

Comment: You have to use the `Output()` decorator

Comment: I tried and didn't success with it. can you giv eme example how to declare it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your event is not bubbling. Try it:

```typescript
.dispatchEvent(new Event('customEvent', { bubbles: true }));
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/SLjOMnBkdrQ0qPeh9DBJ?p=preview)**

Comment: Can I pass event args here too?

Comment: Yes, use detail

Comment: where do I put it?

Comment: Here is en example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42957305/angular2-can-i-pass-custom-parameters-to-host-listener-event

Comment: Use CustomEvent in this case https://plnkr.co/edit/pp6sgnrmtdoY2c7Wzh8h?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Use [`@Output()`](https://angular.io/api/core/Output) to have custom events inside your components. In the example below it is triggered while clicking on a `div`, but you can obviously have it emit whenever. Try to avoid the use of `nativeElement` as much as possible, because this will prevent running your application in any other environment, but the browser

**parent**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'parent',
   template: `<child (customEvent)="onCustomEvent($event)"></child>`
})
export class ParentComponent {

  onCustomEvent(response: string): void {
    console.log(response);
  }
}
```

**child**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'child',
   template: `<div (click)="customEvent.emit('blabla')"></div>`
})
export class ChildComponent {

  @Output()
  customEvent: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  
}
```